# Information about piece of code concerning Brackets and Templates

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates, brackets

This is a part of the code:

```
    tmp<scalarField> nu(const label patchi) const
    {
        return nu_.boundaryField()[patchi];
    }
```

I don't really understand the meaning of brackets after functions parentheses. Is this correct syntax and what does it actually mean?

Second question would be about this "tmp". Is that standart syntax of writing temptates or one can choose everything and write for example hallo.scalarField> or example.scalarField>.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The syntax is valid.  What it means depends on what `boundaryField()` returns.

Comment: does that mean that boundaryField() takes an Array as an input?

Comment: First, one question per question please. Second, are you asking if templates have to be named "tmp" or about the syntax of `tmp<scalarField>`?

Comment: can i for example somehow choose and write "hallo<scalarField>" or it always should be with "tmp" in front

Comment: `tmp` is the name of the function, and a name of a function can contain alphabets (A to z, upper or lower case), numbers and underscores `_`, provided that the name doesn't begin with a number.

Comment: i thought that here "nu" is name of the function... tmp<scalarField> nu(const label patchi) const , but not "tmp"

Comment: Ah, you're right actually, I screwed up. tmp is a type/class name, and the same naming rules apply also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `boundaryField()` returns something that supports `[]` syntax, that is valid. For example, if `foo` is a function that returns a reference to an array, `foo()[0]` would get the first element of said array.